# Access 2010 Write Conflicts with SQL Server 2005 Backend

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I recently upsized an Access 2010 database to use SQL 2005 as the back end database using SSMA for Access.  The migration was completed without problems but now users are getting a write conflict anytime they try to change something, even text in a description field.  SSMA inserted a timestamp field in each table, which I thought would prevent the write conflicts.  Is there something I need to do to Access to force it to use the timestamp field?

The error is:

"This record has been changed by another user since you started editing it.  If you save the record, you will overwrite the changes the other user made."

While researching this I've tried other approaches such as setting BIT or REAL fields to NOT NULL and inserting default values.  This made no change to the issue.  The write conflict even happens when updating an Nvarchar(MAX) field.  I changed that field to Nvarchar(255) but the error still occurred.

I should point out that Access is using a workgroup mdw file for security.

Can anyone help point me in the correct direction?  I've done several of these migrations before but never had this problem.

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that that bit columns don't allow null. Ensure such bit columns have default set of false (0). Ensure All tables have a timestamp. Ensure that all tables have a have a primary key.

Comment: There is only one bit column.  It is currently set to allow nulls, but it is a small table and I confirmed that there are no null entries in the table.  All tables do have a primary key and a timestamp.  Working on this today I was able to update the fields directly in the table via Access, which leads me to believe the problem is in the Access form.  Can you recommend how I should dig into that?  I'm treading carefully since this is a production application.

Comment: If there is no nulls then disable the allow null for that column and THEN RE-LINK to that table from Access. The form souds like the issue - I would check the default of existing controls.  This would suggest that editing existing records should work, but adding new ones fails.  Also look at forms on-load event to see if code sets up values of controls or columns. And check the forms before change event – again to see if any code "sets" a value of some control to null. ANY bound control to the bit column should have a default for that control is set to false (note how I said false, not 0 or 1)

Comment: Still working through this as time permits.  Yesterday I was reviewing the linked tables and found a reference in Linked Table Manager that points to a second database!  All other tables point to the correct database (database=r&d) but one table points to (DSN=POC;DATABASE=POC;)  I have no idea how this got in the mix, as there were no linked tables until I ran SSMA wizard.  When I try to relink to the same table in the correct database, it says it can't find the table even though I can see it in the table list.  Does this mean anything to anyone?